# Image src producing base64 format instead of the proper url using xpath. How do I decode this to get the proper url?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I am extracting an image from a website.
The image has the following tag :

```
<img src="https://www.nocibe.fr/bibliotheque/produits/NOCIBE/231330_nocibe_baume_a_levres_soyeux_tendre_coco_les_delices_baume_a_levres_soyeux_tendre_coco_9g_300x300.jpg?frz-v=2231">
```

I am using the following xpath variable to extract the image src :

```
image_url = product.xpath('.//preceding-sibling::div[@class="product-item__img"]/img/@src')
```

the response I got is :

```
'IMAGE URL': 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='
```

I need this response instead:

```
'IMAGE URL': 'https://www.nocibe.fr/bibliotheque/produits/NOCIBE/231330_nocibe_baume_a_levres_soyeux_tendre_coco_les_delices_baume_a_levres_soyeux_tendre_coco_9g_300x300.jpg?frz-v=2231'
```

How do I achieve that through xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The data was loading through Javascript. So I viewed the page source and searched for the image url and the image was stored under :

```
data-frz-src="https://www.nocibe.fr/bibliotheque/produits/CLARINS/239292_clarins_milky_boost_lait_maquillant_04_milky_auburn_300x300.jpg?frz-v=2231"
```

So I used

```
image_url = product.xpath('.//preceding-sibling::div[@class="product-item__img"]/img/@data-frz-src') instead of @src
```

It worked like a charm! :)